# Dart async* stream breaks randomly in unit tests

Tags: dart, stream, flutter-test

A simple use-case, I get data lists form the server in chunks.
I want to convert that to a stream. Before that I wanted to test if things are working in a unit test.

**Environment**

- Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Linux)
- Dart SDK version: 2.10.4 (stable)

Below is the simplified code combined in one file.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class BeanList<T> {
  final List<T> list;
  final int count;

  BeanList({this.list, this.count});
}

abstract class PageProvider<T> {
  Future<BeanList<T>> provide();
}

class IntPageProvider implements PageProvider<int> {
  final size = 5;
  final count = 9;
  int offset = 0;

  List<int> _generateList(int startFrom, int size) {
    List<int> list = [];
    for (int i = startFrom; i < startFrom + size; i++) {
      list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
  }

  @override
  Future<BeanList<int>> provide() async {
    final list = _generateList(offset, size);
    print('provide: $list');
    offset += size;
    return BeanList<int>(list: list, count: count);
  }
}

Stream<T> itemStream<T>(PageProvider<T> provider) async* {
  int total;
  int sent = 0;
  bool done = false;

  while (true) {
    final BeanList<T> beanList = await provider.provide();
    final list = beanList.list;
    final count = beanList.count;
    total = beanList.count;

    print('Got count:$count, list:$list');
    for (final item in list) {
      print('yield $item');
      yield item;
      sent++;
      done = sent == total;
      if (done) break;
    }
    if (done) break;
  }
}

void main() {
  test('Randomly breaking stream', () {
    itemStream(IntPageProvider()).listen(print);
  });
}
```

Expected output I should get the numbers 0 through 8, which I sometimes do, but most of the times the test stops at any random location.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in both a pure dart environment and with flutter test. Both have an expected result.

Comment: Added environment info, if in anyway it's related to environment.

Comment: FYI, you can break out of two loops in one `break` statement by using a labeled break: `outerLoop: while (true) { .... for (...) ... if (sent == total) break outerLoop; } }`. Then you won't need the `done` variable and an extra `if` and `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Christopher Moore for your time, I have found the problem.

The problem is with how I'm consuming the stream **within the test**.

Currently it's being done like so.

```dart
test('Randomly breaking stream', () {
    itemStream(IntPageProvider()).listen(print);
});
```

`Stream.listen()` runs asynchronously within the test, with nothing to make the test wait for the stream to be consumed fully. So the test ends and all the process within the test stops abruptly, and hence the random stopping point.

However if we make a few changes to the test.

```dart
test('Test waiting for the stream consumption', () async {
    await itemStream(IntPageProvider()).listen(print).asFuture();
});
```

This makes sure that the test will not end until the stream has been fully consumed.

I hope this will help anyone who falls into the same issue.

Comment: You can also use `wait itemStream(...).forEach(print);`. I recommend *never* using `listen` unless you actually use the returned subscription. Otherwise use `forEach` which returns a future, and which breaks at the first error and completes the returned future with that error. Much safer and better for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make sure your stream is consumed fully is to wrap stream inside a `StreamQueue` (from `async` package) so that the stream can have multiple subscribers and then await for `emitsDone` event.

Example inspired from [official doc](https://github.com/dart-lang/test#stream-matchers):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('process emits a WebSocket URL', () async {
    // Wrap the Stream in a StreamQueue so that we can request events.
    var stdout = StreamQueue(Stream.fromIterable([
      'WebSocket URL:',
      'ws://localhost:1234/',
      'Waiting for connection...'
    ]));

    // Ignore lines from the process until it's about to emit the URL.
    await expectLater(stdout, emitsThrough('WebSocket URL:'));
    
    await expectLater(stdout, emitsThrough(emitsDone));
  });
}Ï
```